# Dynamics CRM Custom WebService error on concurrent responses

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, dynamics-crm, adodb

I developed a custom CRM WebService for a client. The webservice uses CRM SDK to create and update contacts. The webservice works just fine, but it is not fast enough for the project requirements, so the webservice is executed concurrently 4 times, everything works just fine, every record is updated just as it should be updated until there's a moment when the following error is thrown while executing the webservice:

> Error: COM error object information is available. Source: "ADODB.Recordset" error code: 0x800A0BCD Description: "Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record."

Apparently this is related to CRM connection with SQL Server, I haven't found any solution anywhere.

The webservice has only one method that requires a custom XML containing attributes to update.

Comment: In my experience, the most common reason for poor update performance is a synchronous plugin being triggered.

Comment: There isn't any plugin registered, the main issue is to check for each contact existence before creating them or updating them. I do this individually. I don't know if there's an optimal way to do it.

Comment: Can you show the code that is throwing the error and instructions proceeding the error? The CRM Web Service for Create and Update of standard and custom entities is plenty fast. I've achieved 1000+ creates or updates per second with it on light records and records with a heavier data payload still can achieve 500+ creates or updates.

Comment: @LuisM Did you already consider using the ExecuteMultipleRequest to improve performance? In scenarios where I have to deal with CREATE vs UPDATE, I try to identify the existing records (WHERE Id IN ...) and then splitting the list of input items accordingly. If you are dealing with big amounts of input data you'll need to implement some kind of paging approach.

Comment: @Nicknow The error doesn't really tell me when the error is thrown, it's somewhat random, e.g. when excecuting the webservice with the same petitions first it throws the error around 10 minutes after it started, in a second excecution of the exact same petitions nothing happens and everything is updated correctly.

Comment: @Filburt I've considered that approach but due to administrative ridiculous procedures changes are not possible at the moment. but looking for days over the internet it seems to be the only solution since the "1 by 1" approach is being very unpredictable.

Comment: How do you know that the exception is resulting from the CRM API? If you don't know the line of code it could be anywhere in your web service implementation. Did you implement a thread-safe version of the CRM connection in the code (since you are calling it 4 times concurrently?) Can you post some code? How are you handling concurrency? In 10 years of CRM experience I've never seen CRM throw an error referencing ADODB.RecordSet directly (hence why I question the cause of the error being CRM.)

Comment: Thanks for the proper response, you're right the exception couldn't possibly be thrown by CRM API because it's not in the log, I thought it was thrown by CRM API because it implies SSIS. About thread safe problem I don't know how to do that I assumed it was handled just like a web page but I was certainly wrong. Finally I don't really know what part of the code to post.